# Google maps API - save changed (marker) direction

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am working with google maps api v3. When I calcluate the way(based on points saved in variables) and after that simply move one marker (change the way) - how can I save this change?
I need that, because when I change marker position and after that - change the travel mode: the new way is computing without the marker change...

I tired this: http://vikku.info/programming/google-maps-v3/draggable-directions/saving-draggable-directions-saving-waypoints-google-directions-google-maps-v3.htm

```
var new_waypoints = directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0];
origin = new_waypoints.start_location;
destination = new_waypoints.end_location;
var wp = new_waypoints.via_waypoints;
var w = [];
alert(wp.length);
for(var i=0; i<wp.length; i++)
{
    w[i] = [wp[i].lat(),wp[i].lng()]
    alert('w');
}
waypoints = w;
```

But new_waypoints.via_waypoints always return empty array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

```
var new_waypoints = directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0];
        var waypoints_count = directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs.length;
        var w = [];
        origin = new_waypoints.start_location;
        for(var i = 1; i<waypoints_count; ++i)
        {
            w.push({ location: directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[i].start_location, stopover: true });
        }    

        destination = directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[waypoints_count-1].end_location;
        waypoints = w;
```